# Adding values and percentages to pie chart

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm trying to make a pie chart breaking down the split in values between 3 different categories (And yes I know a stacked bar chart would be better, but I don't really have a choice in the matter). I figured out how to make the pie using +coord_polar on a stacked bar plot, and hide the ticks/axis labels, but I need to include that actual values, as well as percentage of total, within each slice of the pie chart, and I'm not sure how to do that. Here's the code I'm using (the data I'm working with is confidential, so I've replaced it with some simulated data).

```
library(ggplot2)

simuldata <- data.frame(Category = LETTERS[1:3], 
                        value = c(196, 149,127))

piechart <- ggplot(simuldata, aes(x="", y=value, fill=Category)) +
  geom_bar(width=1, stat="identity") +
  coord_polar("y", start=0) +
  xlab("") +
  ylab("Value") +
  theme(axis.text.x=element_blank(),axis.ticks.x=element_blank())

piechart
```

[image: Which produces this chart]

How would I go about adding the values and percentages to each slice?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is super-straightforward with the `ggstatsplot` package function `ggpiestats` (https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/ggstatsplot/vignettes/ggpiestats.html):

```r
# data
simuldata <- data.frame(Category = LETTERS[1:3],
                        value = c(196, 149, 127))

# plot
ggstatsplot::ggpiestats(data = simuldata,
                        main = Category,
                        counts = value)
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2018-10-11 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.1)</sup>

Answer (score 7):

You can add a `geom_text()` layer, positioning each label to be stacked & vertically aligned in the middle:

```
piechart +
  geom_text(aes(label = paste0(value,
                               " (",
                               scales::percent(value / sum(value)),
                               ")")),
            position = position_stack(vjust = 0.5))
```

[image: plot]

Comment: One of the best solutions to this type of plot! Thanks!